# Ubuntu 22.04lts with 32bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

Recently I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I started to install drivers and effects for desktop home page. After I installed applications, messages about arch 1386 and i386 started to appear in the terminal.

The last application was wine, and I cannot use it because I don't have those archs. I tried to install the arch 1386 and i386.
I visited many websites and tried everything, nothing worked.
Now i used that code:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I get this:

```
kyrillos@kyrillos-Aspire-VN7-791:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
[sudo] parola pentru kyrillos: 
dpkg: eroare: eroare de configurare

: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: opțiune necunoscuta „foreign-architecture”
```

Comment: `sudo mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch $HOME` and try again.

Comment: now it show me that:
kyrillos@kyrillos-Aspire-VN7-791:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
pkg-config-dpkghook: warning: Architecture 1386 not defined in architecture tables, ignored

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` please.

Comment: for the first i get amd64

Comment: for the second i get i386 and 1386

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386`

Comment: I agree with @nobody since "arch 1386" does not exist as an architecture.